# Is it possible to delete an external object reference (variable) from within a function without using exec, eval, compile?

Tags: python

I believe I am on my way to thoroughly understanding [how Python uses variables and references](http://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php), etc, and how they are passed between functions.

As a result of the way Python does things, if I pass a reference variable to a function and attempt to delete the variable inside:

```
class C(): pass
c = C()
def euthanize(patient): del patient
euthanize(c)
```

The external object reference will not be deleted because the function has only removed a local reference variable (which was created when the function was called), not the reference variable from the external context:

```
assert c #No error
```

This is also the case for a class:

```
class C():
    def die(self): c.__del__() #same result for 'del c' here 
    def __del__(self): pass
c = C()
c.die()
assert c #No error
```

This leads me to believe that there is no way, aside from using something like `exec` or `eval`, to delete a variable from outside of the context in which it was created. Is this correct?

### Clarification

I'm sure I'm going to get a lot of "Why would you want to do this?" comments. Please refrain. I have come to understand that, for Python, if there isn't a somewhat straight forward way to accomplish a task, then it is probably something I shouldn't be doing in the first place and I should look into another approach. I am asking the question because I want to make sure I am correct that this is one of those situations, and therefore not something most people will find that they need to accomplish (and of course, if you REALLY DO need to do it, there is always `exec`!). I have noticed people are VERY quick to ask "WHY WOULD YOU WANT TO...?" on SO. [This is understandable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but sometimes very annoying. Please just don't do it in this case, alright?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you did `euthanize(88)`?

Comment: Same thing as happens when I pass any other object. Essentially nothing.

Comment: I guess you have your answers, but I don't really understand what you mean.  I'm asking what you would expect if this worked like you want it to.  In the hypothetical world where there is a way to do this, you expect something to happen when you do `euthanize(c)`, so expecting nothing to happen when you pass `euthanize(88)` is not "the same thing".

Comment: Gotcha. I'd expect, somehow, for the function to be aware of the object reference which it was passed and delete that object reference instead of receiving the object itself and deleting a new, local reference to the passed object. I realize now though, after thinking it through more, that I'm essentially asking how to make python not be python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically right, but I think the reason is somewhat broader than you seem to believe.  As discussed in the link you mentioned, arguments are passed "by object reference".  In other words, when you do `euthanize(c)`, `euthanize` only gets the object referred to by `c`; it doesn't know how you referrred to it.  In this case you used a bare name `c`, but `euthanize` doesn't know that.  You might not have used a variable at all; your example would be equivalent if it was `euthanize(C())`, in which case there is never any name that refers to the C instance.

So, the reason you can't delete a "variable" from the enclosing namespace is that what you are trying to delete is a *name* in the enclosing namespace, while function arguments pass only *values*.  (This isn't pass-by-value, though, because the value is an object reference, which is mentioned in your link so I'm assuming you get what I mean here.)

Your example with `__del__` is a bit of a red herring.  `__del__` is not really deleting anything.  It *may be* called if there are no further references to an object, but calling `del c` in your second example might or might not result in `c.__del__` being called (right away or later).  So even doing `c = C()` and then `c.__del__()` right in the same global namespace wouldn't delete the variable (that is, the name) called `c`.

As ch3ka's answer suggests, the only way to delete a name is to pass it around as a string and then use it to to do something like `del globals(someName)`.  However, even this won't always work; it works for globals, but you can't, for instance, use it in a nested function to delete a local variable of the enclosing function.

Comment: Right I do understand the GC in python and how del doesn't necessarily call the destructor right away. Thanks for pointing that out though. This is a very helpful explanation of why it just doesn't make sense to do this in python.

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it, but probably not what you had in mind:

```
>>> class C(): pass
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> def euthanize(patient):
...   del globals()[patient]
... 
>>> euthanize('c')
>>> c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

another way, not requiring the patient to be passed as string (but still does not clear closures and such):

```
>>> def euthanize(patient):
...  for p in [x[0] for x in 
               globals().items() if 
                    x[1] is patient]:
...    del globals()[p]
... 
>>> c
<__main__.C object at 0x7fe8c4a3d518>
>>> euthanize(c)
>>> c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I had in mind but I didn't mention it as a constraint so I guess `globals` is fair game!

Comment: The second example is a bit dangerous.  It will delete *all* global variables referring to the object, so if you do `c = C()` and then `d = c`, it will remove both `c` and `d`.  It's not totally clear if this is what's desired by the question, but I don't think it is.  Also, I think you mean `if x[1] is patient` there, not `if x[1] is c`.

Comment: yes, you should never let this run on... `5` or such ;) In fact, you should NEVER run this. and yes, `c` was a typo, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a way that you can sort-of kind-of do this. You have to use something like a container or a class attribute.

For example:

```
def euthanize(patient,index): del patient[index]
class C: pass
L = [C()]
euthanize(L,0)
assert len(L) == 0
```

This isn't exactly what I was asking in the question above, but it is similar because it does remove the external strong reference to the object `L[0]` which was created in the above code, and the object will eventually be GC'd. This can be tested using `weakref.finalize`:

```
import weakref
L = [C()]
weakref.finalize(L[0],lambda: print("L[0] finalized!"))
euthanize(L,0) #OUTPUT: L[0] finalized!
```

However, to be precise, the function is not deleting an object reference. `L` is the object reference. The function simply manipulates `L`. EDIT: And as BrenBarn noted below, if there are any *other* references to the member of `L` I am trying to euthanize, those are not removed.

Here's how it would look using a class attribute:

```
c = type('C',(object,),{})()
setattr(c,'X',1)
def euthanizeX(obj): del obj.X
assert c.X #AttributeError (expected)
```

Comment: Right, again there you're not really manipulating a name, you're just manipulating a value (the list, by removing an element from it).  You can only do this if the reference to the `C()` object is part of some object that allows you to manipulate it this way.  Also, the only reason it removes "all strong references" is because you only created one such reference, which you then deleted.  If you also do `M = [L[0]]` after you create `L`, then you would have to euthanize both L[0] and M[0] for the weakref to go away.

Comment: Understood. This has been helpful!

Comment: Glad to hear it! I think one important thing to understand is that not all "object references" are equal in Python. You can have many kinds of reference, like a bare name (what would usually be called a "variable"), a list element, an attribute of an object, etc. Only the bare name is a "primitive" reference in the sense that the "pointing" from the referring expression to its target is atomic, opaque and not hookable. Something like `L[0]`or `L.blah` is quite different because the L object "controls" what happens when you do `[0]` or `.blah` to it, so you can hook in there if L allows it.